# In Jquery Img Tag in not populating image from DB because Src appending View path location in source that i cant remove ?? MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, image, model-view-controller, imagesource

I have MVC application view page is under Home folder.

my image control is like,

```
<img id="user_img" height="100" width="90" style="border:solid" />
```

i am saving image in folder `Img` on the same level like `App_data , App_Start` etc.

i populating this img from response i am getting in Ajax.

```
$("#user_img").attr("src", response.EmpPic);
```

value i am getting from database is `~/Img/imageName.jpg`

now according to jquery it set its source value but because my view is in Home folder it does not get image and show source i checked in browser developer  tool is ,

```
"http://localhost:53798/Home/~/Img/imageName.jpg"
```

It will work if it should be like,

```
http://localhost:53798/Img/WelcomeScan124117716.jpg
```

I might change the source of image but how to edit above address it is getting due to view folder `"/Home/"`

Hopes for your suggestion thanks

Comment: What is the value in response.EmpPic ?

Comment: this is response ~/Img/imageName.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it without the "~". You only need this in a few cases in Razor. It should work without it.

Comment: i already tried it because it is using View Folder it appends Home in src location

Comment: You are right after removing ~ its working ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try generating your path on the `Controller` side like this:

```
response.EmpPic=Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"/Img/", fileName)
```

This would give you the path of the current directory where the Img folder resides.